# What is the official JavaScript logo/icon?

Tags: javascript

Is there an official JavaScript logo/icon or there is no official logo or icon at all? If not, which icon do you consider to be the most representative when refering to JavaScript? I am just curious, because PHP has an recognizable icon, perl has, ruby, python etc. all the other languages have some sort of official logo or icon.

Comment: JS [11 more to go]

Comment: link to that logo/icon?

Comment: This is not a user experience question. Questions should be related to user experience problems that you have a question about. Requesting information on a logo isn't such a question and isn't suited to a StackExchange site.

Comment: actually this is a user experience question, most notably because user experience is subjective.

Comment: https://github.com/voodootikigod/logo.js/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**There is probably no "official" icon**, because there is no body officially "governing" JavaScript. See also [this related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606212/419956) about the "official" manual on JavaScript. Instead, JavaScript is a derivative of ECMAScript. Glancing over the [official ECMAScript website](http://www.ecmascript.org/) I don't see any official logo's or icons for ECMAScript either, not even in the specification documents (for version 3 nor for version 5).

Interestingly, the [Wikipedia article on JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) showed in past this logo, which I'd personally never seen before:

[image: Unofficial logo from JSConf EU 2011]

In response to your second question: I guess if I must choose then I would go for any icon in my existing house style with these two features:

- Capitals "JS"
- Indication that the icon's about code

---

To add to this, see there's this related icon:

- [image: JScript icon] [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript): Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript

Comment: js logo (the one from wikipedia) is the unofficial logo, because JavaScript is owned by oracle. you can read more here: http://www.2ality.com/2011/10/logo-js.html and you can get it here: https://github.com/voodootikigod/logo.js

Comment: @Sparky this is by no means crap - as JavaScript *is* in fact a trademark of Oracle Corporation as the [USPTO states](http://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=75026640&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch)...

Comment: What I was saying was that JavaScript, the language, is not owned by Oracle. The trademark is, yes.

Comment: Note: Wikipedia article on JavaScript is fixed and this dubious logo is gone